# Mapping Underscore Character In VIM

Tags: vim

I've been trying to create a mapping in VIM to "move" a line up in the editor. So I tried adding both of these to my .vimrc:

```
map _ ddP
```

didn't work.

```
map <underscore> ddP
```

also didn't work.
Does _ have a special meaning or something? Why isn't this working the way I want it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try `ddP` yourself, without using any mapping: it should *cancel itself*... Because it will place the deleted line exactly in the same place.

Did you forget `k` to go one line up? Try this:

```
:noremap _ ddkP
```

Note: always use `:noremap` instead of `:map` (particularly in scripts, see help).

#### Or...

Or maybe your underscore key is the beginning of a longer mapping, then Vim waits for the end of it. To check this, just run `:map _` to see which mappings begin with `_`.

A last thing: `<underscore>` is not a valid key in Vim; see `:h key-notation` for more info.

Comment: Thank you! That did it! I didn't even stop to think and realize that ddP would cancel each other out.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore doesn't have a special meaning, you just map it to paste a line to the same place where it was before. Try this:

```
map _ ddkP
```

Or, better yet, use a [non-recursive](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27remap%27) version of the mapping:

```
noremap _ ddkP
```